# The option for a voip client with the Action.Call intent in Android

Tags: android, voip, skype, phone-call

I've created an app that can call a number specified in a sharedpreferencemenu by the click of an button.
All this is work perfectly.

Now my question is:
For example when you have a voip client or skype on your phone and you select a contact or you dial a number you will get a choice with wich one you want to perform the phone call with.

But in my app it goes straight to the default android caller.

this is my code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final String callnumber = prefs.getString("call", "");
    callbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.callbutton);


 // Add PhoneStateListener
    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    // Call Button Listener
callbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override          
 public void onClick(View arg0) 
 {              
    String posted_by = callnumber;
    String uri = "tel:" + posted_by.trim() ;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});}
```

So my final question is:
Is it possible that when I click the call button in my app I will get the choice which application should perform the call?

Answer (score 0):

I've never made such implementation, but I think you can do it. Maybe if you add to your application some [IntentFilters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) coupled with the Android's capability to launch others applications you can achieve you goal.

This bellow code shows how you open a Skype app and dial to a given/passed contact by his name:

```
   Intent sky = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
   sky.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + name));
   startActivity(sky);
```

I think you can implement a similar behavior, opening the application that you want, passing to it the desired/needed arguments.

I hope that it helps you in some way! :)